# Get all phone notifications using React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to build a notification history-type app, and I need to find a way to intercept all push notifications a phone gets and log them in the app. How could I do such a thing? Thank you!

Comment: Do you target only notifications pushed by your app or all notification received by device?

Comment: @FistonEmmanuel All notifications received by the device

Comment: For user privacy purposes, No OS should expose this information to third-party apps.

Comment: Some notification contains user personal information like SMS or financial transaction alerts.

Comment: @FistonEmmanuel So there's no way of doing it?

Comment: Legally not allowed